# Running my own Dynamic DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dynamic-dns

I have a few servers on which I run nameserver trough webmin/bind. Now I have a computer at home that I want to access from anywhere in the world, the only problem is, my IP adress changes often.

Ideally I want to create a name, for example, myhomepc.mydomain.com, which always points to my IP adress.

This means that the A record of this domain has to change according to my IP adress.

Is this possible? I am doing my work trough webmin.

Comment: today you may use PyDDNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolutely easiest solution is to use one of the free dynamic DNS services like dyndns.com or no-ip.com (Google for more options).

If you need to have your home pc on your "mydomain.com", I suggest using a CNAME pointing to the dyndns fqdn.

Comment: +1 This could be an option. If there is no other way im gonna take the easy road. Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

If you run your own bind server, have a look at proper Dynamic DNS rather than options like dyndns and no-ip.com. This uses features available as standard in Bind to update the zone directly. It's a bit more involved than setting up a CNAME for one of the above services, but at least you have full control.

There's a webmin module that will seemingly handle is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/b9ddns/), although I haven't used it, so don't know how good it is.

For details on how to set it up manually, you can have a look [here](http://blog.jasonantman.com/2010/04/bind9-dynamic-dns/).

Comment: +1 for suggesting to do it myself. Are you sure the webmin module is to solve this problem. I think the module is for a webmin system that is running on an dynamic IP. My webmin server has a static IP, the pc that I want to point to from within webmin has a dynamic IP.

Comment: As I said, I haven't used the webmin module, but it does mention dynamic zones. I tend to prefer to get down and dirty and figure out how stuff works, so I did it the manual way. The most difficult part was writing the script to do the nsupdate.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a host somewhere for yourdomain.com, they usually provide a dynamic dns feature in the toolset. I know bluehost does (because i actually do what you are trying to do). It works great, and if you are behind a router, just a simple NAT with a port forwarding rule in your router and you are all set with yourmachine.yourdomain.com.

I know you said your IP changes a lot, but if your machine is on all the time, it shouldn't change, but i don't know that much information about your setup.

Comment: Does bluehost still offer this feature? I have my own domain registered with them but I'm not able to find any Dynamic DNS feature. Where can i find it?

Comment: adding an answer that i was TOLD. was "bluehost does not have that functionality." though reading split71 response I'm sure they do but just don't know how to help me.